# Value from arbitrary restriction vs value from sharing

Tags: ethics, free-will, values, love, counterfactuals

Let's take a simplifying example to illustrate two opposite worldviews:

- Some people see value in intangible things when access to these things is restricted as if sharing was leading to a value loss: for example, people who will keep things private to themselves because sharing them would be seen as a loss, or some people in a monogamous context who will give more value to a relationship when other opportunities are dismissed.
- On the opposite, some people will see value in intangible things when shared, having a completely different take on the preceding examples, and interpreting them as a loss of value instead of a gain.

Sorry if these descriptions are very handwavy but that is why I am posting. I am looking for resources to try to understand what's behind these worldviews and what it boils down to. I am looking for keywords to search, books, academic papers that address this dichotomy in a rigorous way to better understand what's behind. I can imagine links with counterfactuality (value given to things by what could have happened but did not happened), free will (value given from the choice between two things), and property, but I do not have a clear picture in mind of how all of this is related (and I'm not interested by simplifying arbitrary value judgments which would boil down to people of the second category are "better" than people of the first one, this is not what I'm looking for).

Comment: From antiquity as [recorded](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92488/why-does-plato-rank-numbers-fundamentally-below-certain-other-ideas) by Plato it all boils down to the idea of the *good* which is beyond all other ideas such as number, shape, wealth, fame, etc, with its supreme (phonetic) form as God/Gawd, ie, depends squarely on your own philosophy...